# call stopFlipping and startFlipping from RemoteViews

Tags: android, android-widget

is there a way to call `stopFlipping` function from `AppWidgetProvider` using `RemoteViews`'s object.

As i have seen a function in `RemoteViews` i.e. `setInt , setString` etc but they all have the third parameter which needs to be filled with some value.

where as to call no argument function like `stopFlipping` or `startFlipping` there isn't any way.

Comment: Do you found any solution regard this ?

Answer (score 1):

`startFlipping()` and `stopFlipping()` are definitely not accessible via `RemoteViews`, as those methods are not annotated with `@android.view.RemotableViewMethod` in the source code.

One workaround you could try is to use `setInt()` to modify the `flipInterval`, setting it to a normal value where you would normally use `startFlipping()` and setting it to something really long (e.g., a year) where you would normally use `stopFlipping()`.

Comment: if i will go with the workaround then i got use `  android:autoStart=true` and initially i dont want to do that and without autostart `setFlipInterval` wont work

Comment: @Hunt: Then do not use `ViewFlipper`, I suppose.

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you suggest what alternative Widget will help me to implement flipping like ViewFlipper does?

Comment: @Herry: I am not aware of anything available for an app widget that offers automatic flipping, probably out of respect for the user's battery.